# Google App Engine appcfg.py attempting Python precompile stage for php55 runtime?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Since the (awesome) release of php55 runtime for Google AppEngine, I am getting a precompilation failed warning (non-fatal) during deployments.

Can someone confirm this is just because the appcfg.py recompilation phase thinks the new "php55" runtime string should be treated as Python rather than skipping recompilation?

Cheers!

Tom

Comment: Yes, looks like there's exactly the glitch you observed.  You can use the `--no_precompilation` option to avoid the warning -- and, please open a bug about this at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list , thanks!

Comment: Cheers! - bug raised, https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11696